# Antd's getFieldDecorator for other packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'd like to integrate [react-mapbox-autocomplete](http://react-mapbox-autocomplete) with Antd's `getFieldDecorator`.

But it seems to Antd's getFieldDecorator only support for their own components.

Is there any way to use it for other packages like `react-map-autocomplete`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make `getFieldDecorator` to work with every custom component that is not an `antd` component.

As mentioned in the docs, you need to use the **injected** props from [`getFieldDecorator`](https://ant.design/components/form/#this.props.form.getFieldDecorator(id,-options)).

> After wrapped by getFieldDecorator, value(or other property defined by valuePropName) onChange(or other property defined by trigger) props will be added to form controls.

As this is a very common question, here is some production code example:

Here we use a custom component `SliderNumber` with `getFieldDecorator`.

```
<Form.Item label={TOLERANCE.label}>
  {getFieldDecorator(TOLERANCE.field)(<SliderNumber />)}
</Form.Item>
```

And within its implementation, we use the injected `onChange` and `value` from `getFieldDecorator`.

```
const SliderNumber = forwardRef(({ onChange, value: initial }, ref) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initial);

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(value);
  }, [onChange, value]);

  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <FlexBox.Item span={SPAN}>
        <Slider value={value} onChange={setValue} />
      </FlexBox.Item>
      <FlexBox.Item span={SPAN_REST}>
        <InputNumber value={value} onChange={setValue} />
      </FlexBox.Item>
    </FlexBox>
  );
});
```

Note that sometimes it is easier to just use `ref` without implementing the `onChange` like above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dennis. Is there any example for me?